# Tcpclient stream.ReadAsync does not return 0 when socket/stream closes?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, async-await

I'm using TcpClient.Stream.ReadAsync to receive data in a loop. Traditionally, windows sockets return 0 when the socket closes gracefully. With the following code, the only time ReadAsync returns is when there is actual data. If I close the remote app (gracefully or forcefully) or even if I call Stream.Close() on the TcpClient, the ReadAsync still doesn't complete or throw an exception. How do I get ReadAsync to complete?

```
var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(conn.buffer, 0, Connection.BufferSize, ct);

if (amountRead == 0)
    break; //end of stream.
else
{
    //Process Received Data here
}
```

Comment: See examples on following webpage.  The examples are for sockets but sockets can be replaced with an class the inherits sockets like TcpClient or TCPListener. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's actually different Socket API i.e. BeginSend and BeginReceive. My question is regarding the newer await/async api: ReadAsync.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: By the way, `Stream.ReadAsync` is just a wrapper around `Stream.BeginRead` and `Stream.EndRead`.

Comment: It doesn't return at all, no error code, no exception. The only time it returns is when it actually receives data.

Comment: @PauloMorgado The default implementation is, but `Stream.ReadAsync` is virtual and can be overridden by inheriting classes. (However to be fair to you, [I checked the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs) and `NetworkStream` does not override `ReadAsync`)

Answer (score 2):

No, the `ReadAsync` reading semantics are exactly the same as `BeginRead` and `Read`. The read *will* return a 0-byte result at the end of the stream.

It's possible that the remote server is not closing the socket gracefully. Public-facing servers often do this to avoid the 4-way closing handshake. Unfortunately, this means that you as the client need to detect when the socket is closed. Traditionally, this is done by using a keepalive message or packet. I have a [blog post with more details](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html); but the key is it has to be an *active* detection - i.e., the client has to send something to detect the connection is no longer there.

On a side note, I'm not sure what closing the *stream* would do. But I'm fairly certain that closing the *socket* (`TcpClient`) would cause the stream read to complete with an error.

Comment: I can confirm that await stream.ReadAsync() will never return if the server sending the data does not close the socket graciously (e.g. using StreamSocket.Dispose()).